# Persisting Path objects with spring-data-mongodb respositories

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

In a project I use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.5.3` and therefore `spring-data-mongodb:3.2.3` and have an entity class that simplified looks like this:

```java
@Document
public class Task {
  @Id
  private final String id;
  private final Path taskDir;
  ...

  // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

with a default Spring MongoDB repository that allows to retrieve the task via its id.

The Mongo configuration looks as such:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
    "path.to.repository"
}, mongoTemplateRef = MongoConfig.MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoSettings.class)
public class MongoConfig extends MongoConfigurationSupport {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
  public static final String MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF = "mongoAlTemplate";

  private final MongoSettings mongoSettings;

  @Autowired
  public MongoConfig(final MongoSettings mongoSettings) {
    this.mongoSettings = mongoSettings;
  }

  @Bean(name = "ourMongo", destroyMethod = "close")
  public MongoClient ourMongoClient() {
    MongoCredential credential =
        MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoSettings.getUser(),
                                         mongoSettings.getDb(),
                                         mongoSettings.getPassword());
    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
        // enable optimistic locking for @Version and eTag usage
        .writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED)
        .credential(credential)
        .applyToSocketSettings(
            builder -> builder.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(
            builder -> builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .minSize(5).maxSize(20))
//        .applyToClusterSettings(
//            builder -> builder.requiredClusterType(ClusterType.REPLICA_SET)
//                .hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("host1", 27017),
//                                     new ServerAddress("host2", 27017)))
//                .build())
        .build();
    return MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
  }

  @Override
  @Nonnull
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return mongoSettings.getDb();
  }

  @Bean(name = MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF)
  public MongoTemplate ourMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(ourMongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  }
}
```

On attempting to save a task via `taskRepository.save(task)` Java ends up in a StackOverflowError

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:160)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1341)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:881)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:740)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:657)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:633)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:657)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:633)
    ...
```

On annotating the path object `taskDir` in the `Task` class with `@Transient` I'm able to persist the task, so the problem seems to be related with Java/Spring/MongoDB being unable to handle `Path` objects directly.

My next attempt was to configure a custom converter inside the `MongoConfig` class to convert between `Path` and `String` representations:

```java
@Override
protected void configureConverters(
  MongoCustomConversions.MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter converterConfigurationAdapter) {
  LOG.info("configuring converters");
  converterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverter(new Converter<Path, String>() {
    @Override
    public String convert(@Nonnull Path path) {
      return path.normalize().toAbsolutePath().toString();
    }
  });
  converterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverter(new Converter<String, Path>() {
    @Override
    public Path convert(@Nonnull String path) {
      return Paths.get(path);
    }
  });
}
```

though the error remained. I then defined a direct conversion between the `Task` object and a `DBObject` as showcased in this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-index-annotations-converter#converters)

```java
@Override
protected void configureConverters(
  MongoCustomConversions.MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter converterConfigurationAdapter) {
  LOG.info("configuring converters");
  converterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverter(new Converter<Task, DBObject>() {
    @Override
    public DBObject convert(@Nonnull Task source) {
    DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
      if (source.getTaskDirectory() != null) {
        dbObject.put("taskDir", source.getTaskDirectory().normalize().toAbsolutePath().toString());
      }
      ...
      return dbObject;
    }
  });
}
```

and I still get a `StackOverflowError` in return. Through the log statement I added I see that Spring called into the `configureConverters` method and therefore should have registered the custom converters.

Why do I still get the `StackOverflowError` though? How do I need to tell Spring to treat `Path` objects as `String`s while persisting and on read-time convert the `String` value to a `Path` object back again?

---

Update:

I've now followed the example given in [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-configuration) and refactored the converter to its own class

```java
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

@WritingConverter
public class TaskWriteConverter implements Converter<Task, Document> {

  @Override
  public Document convert(@Nonnull Task source) {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.put("_id", source.getId());
    if (source.getTaskDir() != null) {
      document.put("taskDir", source.getTaskDir().normalize().toAbsolutePath().toString());
    }
    return document;
  }
}
```

The configuration in the `MongoConfig` class now looks like this:

```java
  @Override
  protected void configureConverters(
      MongoCustomConversions.MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter adapter) {
    LOG.info("configuring converters");
    adapter.registerConverter(new TaskWriteConverter());
    adapter.registerConverter(new TaskReadConverter());
    adapter.registerConverter(new Converter<Path, String>() {
      @Override
      public String convert(@Nonnull Path path) {
        return path.normalize().toAbsolutePath().toString();
      }
    });
    adapter.registerConverter(new Converter<String, Path>() {
      @Override
      public Path convert(@Nonnull String path) {
        return Paths.get(path);
      }
    });
  }
```

After changing the logging level for `org.springframework.data` to `debug` I see in the logs that these converters also got picked up:

```
2021-09-23 14:09:20.469 [INFO ] [           main] MongoConfig                              configuring converters 
2021-09-23 14:09:20.480 [DEBUG] [           main] CustomConversions                        Adding user defined converter from class com.acme.Task to class org.bson.Document as writing converter. 
2021-09-23 14:09:20.480 [DEBUG] [           main] CustomConversions                        Adding user defined converter from class org.bson.Document to class com.acme.Task as reading converter. 
2021-09-23 14:09:20.481 [DEBUG] [           main] CustomConversions                        Adding user defined converter from interface java.nio.file.Path to class java.lang.String as writing converter. 
2021-09-23 14:09:20.481 [DEBUG] [           main] CustomConversions                        Adding user defined converter from class java.lang.String to interface java.nio.file.Path as reading converter.
```

However, I see the that most of the converters are added multiple times, i.e. I find a log for `Adding converter from class java.lang.Character to class java.lang.String as writing converter.` actually 4 times before the application hits the `save` method on the repository. As my custom converters are only added the 3rd time all of these converters appear in the logs, I have a feeling that they are somehow overwritten as the logs in the last "iteration" don't include my custom converters.

The test case that reproduces that issue is as follows:

```java
@ŚpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SomeIT {
  
  @Autowired
  private TaskRepository taskRepository;
  ...


  @Test
  public void testTaskPersistence() throws Exception {
    Task task = new Task("1234", Paths.get("/home/roman"));
    taskRepository.save(task);
  }

   ...
}
```

The test-method is only used to investigate into the current persistence issue and under normal conditions shouldn't be there at all as the integration test tests the upload of a large file, its preprocessing  and so on. This integration tests however fails due to Spring not being able, at least it seems so, to store entities that contain Path objects.

Note that for simple entities I do not have issues in persisting them with the outlined setup and I also seem them in the dockerized MongoDB.

I haven't had time yet to dig deeper into why Spring has such problems with `Path` objects or why my custom converters suddenly disappear in the last iteration of the `CustomConversions` log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the way the `mongoTemplate` is configured does "overwrite" any specified custom converters and thus Spring is not able to make use of these and convert `Path` to `String` and vice versa.

After changing the `MongoConfig` to the one below, I'm finally able to use my custom converters and thus persist entities as expected:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
    "path.to.repository"
}, mongoTemplateRef = MongoConfig.MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoSettings.class)
public class MongoConfig extends MongoConfigurationSupport {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
  public static final String MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF = "mongoAlTemplate";

  private final MongoSettings mongoSettings;

  @Autowired
  public MongoConfig(final MongoSettings mongoSettings) {
    this.mongoSettings = mongoSettings;
  }

  @Bean(name = "ourMongo", destroyMethod = "close")
  public MongoClient ourMongoClient() {
    MongoCredential credential =
        MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoSettings.getUser(),
                                         mongoSettings.getDb(),
                                         mongoSettings.getPassword());
    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
        // enable optimistic locking for @Version and eTag usage
        .writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED)
        .credential(credential)
        .applyToSocketSettings(
            builder -> builder.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(
            builder -> builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .minSize(5).maxSize(20))
//        .applyToClusterSettings(
//            builder -> builder.requiredClusterType(ClusterType.REPLICA_SET)
//                .hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("host1", 27017),
//                                     new ServerAddress("host2", 27017)))
//                .build())
        .build();
    LOG.info("Mongo client initialized. Connecting with user {} to DB {}",
             mongoSettings.getUser(), mongoSettings.getDb());
    return MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
  }

  @Override
  @Nonnull
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return mongoSettings.getDb();
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoDatabaseFactory ourMongoDBFactory() {
    return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(ourMongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  }

  @Bean(name = MONGO_TEMPLATE_REF)
  public MongoTemplate ourMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(ourMongoDBFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(ourMongoDBFactory());
    MongoCustomConversions customConversions = customConversions();
    MongoMappingContext context = mongoMappingContext(customConversions);
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, context);
    // this one is actually needed otherwise the StackOverflowError re-appears!
    converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
    return converter;
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  @Nonnull
  public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
    return  new MongoCustomConversions(
        Arrays.asList(new PathWriteConverter(), new PathReadConverter())
    );
  }
}
```

So, instead of passing the `MongoClient` and the database name to the `mongoTemplate` directly, a `MongoDatabaseFactory` object holding the above mentioned values and a `MappingMongoConverter` object are passed as input to the template.

Unfortunately, it is necessary to pass the `customConversion` object twice within the `mappingMongoConverter()` method. If not done so, the `StackOverflowError` reappears.

With the given configuration, conversions from `Path` to `String` and `String` to `Path` are now possible and thus no custom conversions from `Task` to `Document` and vice versa are currently needed.